# Tabbarcontroller,NavigationController and viewController

Tags: ios4, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have made a Tabbar based application in that i have three tab.

each of tab has NavigationController..

In one of the tab (lets take in the 1st tab), i have a UIButton in that FirstViewController that is rootViewController of NavigationController..by clicking on button i navigate to the secondViewController...

Now i switch to second tab. and again switching back to 1st tab i got secondViewController open.

but i don't want that....i want to go on the FirstViewController while switching back to 1st tab...

is it possible ???

if yes then can any1 help me to solve it out??

any Help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the default behavior of UITabbar controller,so that the user can go back to the view controller which he had left from earlier.You cannot change it.

Comment: thanx aaditya for Replying..
but IOS SDK4.3 has method for navigation controller like:[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
so by using this method is it possible to pop all the viewcontrollers of navigationcontroller, when we switch to this tab???

Comment: you can give it a shot but i don't think that way you would be able to achieve your goal